# Adding site Binding programmatically IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, iis

I am trying to add site binding programmatically. Here is my code:

```
using (ServerManager manager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("serverName"))
{
    manager.Sites["siteName"].Bindings.Add(string.Format("*:{1}:{0}.localhost", clientCode, port), "http");
    manager.CommitChanges();
}
```

I am getting the following Error. How do I get around this?

> UnAuthorizedException: Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {} from machine  failed due to the following error: 80070005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account runs the code must be the administrator of the remote machine and also the DCOM related ports on the remote machine must be opened at firewall.